# Return Users from a specific Location using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the list of all users from a particular place by using the Facebook Graph API. The Link I have used is

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=rasulgarh&fields=name,id&limit=2000&type=place&access_token=

But this returns the groups only with the location as "rasulgarh". I am not able to get the users. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Manually it is possible using the Facebook search. Can you explain why "I can't"?

Comment: Yes you are right, manually its possible but facebook dont provide any api for this, api has some limitations. If you want to search a name on facebook, that you can do : `/search?q=Prachi&type=user` ; but searching users in a location is unfortunately not possible

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect. Keep in mind that the `type` parameter is the OBJECT_TYPE. Searching for `type=place` will return place objects, not user objects. I don't think its currently possible to search for users in a location (that I am aware of, at least.).

Comment: So is there no way to search for users in a particular location? Manually it is possible using the Facebook search. Right?

Comment: Correct. But I am unaware of an equivalent via the API.